# BugSnag Error Boundary Not Logging Error in Bugsnag

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, bugsnag

I have this

```
bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagReact, React)
const ErrorBoundary = bugsnagClient.getPlugin('react')

<ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallbackComponent}>
    <AppContainer />
</ErrorBoundary>

export const ErrorFallbackComponent =  () => <div>An error has occurred</div>
```

however I noticed only error that I actually do   `bugsnagClient.notify(new Error(error.errorMessage));`

I am wondering if I have to add   `bugsnagClient.notify(new Error(error.errorMessage));` into my error boundry and if so how?

I was looking at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) but I am not sure if bugsnag code already has wrapped my code and already has these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the [latest documentation](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/react/#basic-configuration) which highlights how you can create an Error Boundary.

```
const ErrorBoundary = Bugsnag.getPlugin('react').createErrorBoundary(React)

export default () =>
  <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorView}>
    <App />
  </ErrorBoundary>

class ErrorView extends React.Component {
  // This component will be displayed when an error boundary catches an error
}
```

Make sure you are using the React plugin when you initialize Bugsnag:

```
Bugsnag.start({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  plugins: [new BugsnagPluginReact()]
})
```